# HTML/CSS Horizontally Aligned Buttons Not Filling Page As Expected

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make 2 buttons that are horizontally aligned to one another using HTML and CSS. I am just about there but I can not get the buttons to fill the page horizontally. The buttons should be equal in width but they should stretch to fill the page.

I tried making the "li" and "a" tags have a width of 100% but this has no affect. The padding on the buttons "a" tag only affects the left and right not the top and bottom as expected. What am I doing wrong?

Below is my code, a Fiddle, and diagram.

**CSS:**

```
#myButtons {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#myButtons li {
    display: inline;
    border-radius: 10px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 10px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px; 
    border: 2px solid #F00; 
    background-color: #FF0;
    width: 100%; /* Doesn't make any difference */
}
#myButtons a {
    width: 100%; /* Doesn't make any difference */
    padding: 50px; /* Padding is only being applied to the left and right of the button links not the top and bottom as well */
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<p>The button's CSS styles should not affect other elements on the page.</p>
<ul id="myButtons">
  <li><a href="#">Call Us</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Go To Full Site</a></li>
</ul>
<p>The button's CSS styles should not affect other elements on the page.</p>
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/vET6C/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this, this is one of them. Your `li` was set to `display:inline` which ignores the `width` property. Floating them or setting them to `display:inline-block` will solve that problem.

The `a` element is inline by default, so the width was also ignored. Also inline elements apply top and bottom padding not in the way you would expect. I say it this way because I'm not 100% sure how it applies it, but changing it to `inline-block` or `block` would make it work the way you expect.

http://jsfiddle.net/vET6C/1/

```
#myButtons li {
    float:left;
    border-radius: 10px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 10px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px; 
    border: 2px solid #F00; 
    background-color: #FF0;
    width: 50%; /* Doesn't make any difference */
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}
#myButtons a {
    display:block;
    padding:50px;
}
```